# new[] with an overloaded constructor

Tags: c++

my test code

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
    private:
        int a, b;
    public:
        Test();
        Test(int a);
        inline int getA();
        inline int getB();
};

Test::Test() : a(0), b(0) {}

Test::Test(int a) : a(a), b(0) {}

inline int Test::getA() {
    return a;
}

inline int Test::getB() {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    Test* test = new Test(3)[2];
    Test* test2 = new Test[2];
    for(int a = 0; a < 2; ++a) {
        std::cout << "test[" << a << "] = " << test[a].getA() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "test2[" << a << "] = " << test2[a].getA() << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] test;
    delete[] test2;
    return 0;
}
```

the important part is

```
Test* test = new Test(3)[2];
```

which gives error: main.cpp:26:29: error: expected ',' or ';' before '[' token

if I'd written

```
Test* test = new Test(3);
```

it would have run fine (if I then went on and used -> and delete later on in the code, of course).  Is there a different syntax for calling an overloaded constructor with new[] or is it just not possible?

Comment: Can you use `std::vector`?  It was built to do this.

Comment: I could, but I'm just curious about this.

Comment: The only way to have it close to what you have is to use a `std::vector`.  Otherwise you have to initialize all of the elements yourself.

Comment: Oh, ok.  If it's not possible, then that's all the answer I need.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the array like this:

```
Test* test = new Test[2]{3, 3};
```

Note you have to write N 3's for an array of length N.